# Jenkins opens Chrome with limited dimensions

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

I am using Selenium script (in Java) with Jenkins using Chrome browser.
But Jenkins opens Chrome browser with dimension 1040x784, although I tried to increase dimension as desktop browser but failed, it still opens browser with dimensions 1040x784.

I am using this code to increase dimension:

```
Dimension dim=new Dimension(1340, 744);
driver.manage().window().setSize(dim);
```

So in order to open chrome browser with desktop dimension, do I need to add any plugin? Due to this I am not able to automate most of the features with Jenkins.

* I am using Jenkins as my Windows services.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same code as you with jenkins without problem: windows is set to its new size as expected.
I think the issue might be that Chrome does not allow to set the size larger than the dimension of the system's screen.

If you know for sure that your system's screen allows you to reach [1340, 744], then it might be because your chrome driver is not an up to date version.

If it still does not work, below are some tests you might try, to fix the issue:

1. Try to run it with firefox webdriver, and see if you have the same issue. this will discard an issue related to chrome webdriver.
2. Try to set new dimension, but smaller than the 1040, 784, and see if chrome lets you do that. It will discard an issue related to the way you have written your code.
3. does it work fine when you execute it on local ?

Comment: :- Thanks!!I also tried same with Firefox, also my site is not responsive, due to this some of the site features gets disappear when open in 1040,784. As UI table gets distroted and script gets failure, do you have any other alternative.

Comment: I am afraid I don't have any other suggestions regarding this issue. How do you know that dimensions are not being set alright in Jenkins ?

Comment: :- I just printedout the dimensions and in jenkins logs dimensions gets printed out. But in my java code in set driver.manage().window().maximize()